# If something is not real even to worlds that are not real, what is it?

Tags: truth

Suppose you have a world that has demons, angels, and superhumans. All of these things are not real. But, in unreal, you have things that are not real even in the unreal world. Such as a giant 9000 armed turtle. Is this turtle just considered unreal, or does it have a different type of real/unrealness because it is unreal even in unreal worlds? This is like fiction inside of fiction.

Comment: How is it not just fiction? Fictional characters can be portrayed as telling stories.

Comment: But is there a difference to a fiction inside a fictional setting and a fiction inside the real world?

Comment: Things are not true/false; statements are.

Comment: sorry, I meant real.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I fixed it, does it seem better now?

Comment: Also, how do you define "real?" Superman is "real" in the sense that we can talk about him, read about him, and watch him in movies, but he is not "real in the sense that you can shake his hand or have a conversation with him.

Comment: In the tradition of recursion, one might consider a fiction inside a fiction a second-order fiction, but both are fictions nonetheless.

Comment: A 9000 arm turtle is a logical possibility, which a rearrangement of language used for real things can represent. They could be a conjecture, or a fiction. Some people genuinely believe in angels & demons, either literally or as something more metaphorical. The beard of the current king of France, is another kind of unreal. You might be interested in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catu%E1%B9%A3ko%E1%B9%ADi for a way of thinking beyond a real/unreal binary

Answer (score 1):

Fictions not only specify the ontological furniture of fictional worlds, they also specify what the vocabulary means. Absent any definition, we assume the definition extent in the real world. I suspect that most fictions don't re-define the concept of fiction.

One example of a fiction within a fiction is the constant falsification of the past in George Orwell's 1984. There is clearly no difficulty in understanding the idea even though the past which is supposed to be falsified and therefore turned into a fiction is itself a fiction.

The reader regards the past in the fictional world of 1984 as part of the fiction and therefore as itself a fiction. The fictional past resulting from the Party's constant rewriting of history is part of the fiction of 1984 and therefore also seen as a fiction.

What is perhaps more interesting is that the fictitious past created by the Party in the fictional world of 1984 is construed by the reader as a falsification of the true past of 1984. Thus, the reader keeps in mind a sort of complex structure which involves the fictional past of 1984's world, fictionally regarded as true past, and the fictional falsification of it, fictionally regarded as an actual falsification producing a fictional past of what is regarded as the fictional true past of 1984's world.

I have no more complex example than 1984, but this seems enough to demonstrate that human readers are able, to some extent, to adopt a sort of relativistic interpretation of fictional stories and that the human mind has no conceptual difficulty accommodating at least the limited complexity of the 1984 scenario.